# Webpack Broken after installing vuex-persistedstate

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack

I have broken my webpack installation after installing vuex-persistedstate. I have removed the node modules folder and the package-lock.json file and re-installed, but I am still receiving the following error when trying to run my project:

```
npm ERR! client@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@1.0.0 dev script.
```

I have deleted the /node_modules folder and package-lock.json file, and ran the following commands:

```
npm install
npm run build
npm start
```

My package.json file contains the following packages:

```
 "scripts": {
 "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
 "start": "npm run dev",
 "unit": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run",
 "e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
 "test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e",
 "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit test/e2e/specs",
 "build": "node build/build.js"
 },
 "dependencies": {
 "ajv": "^6.10.2",
 "axios": "^0.19.0",
 "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
 "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
 "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0",
 "jquery": "^3.5.1",
 "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
 "vue": "^2.5.2",
 "vue-cookies": "^1.5.13",
 "vue-js-modal": "^1.3.31",
 "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
 "vuejs-dialog": "^1.4.1",
 "vuex": "^3.5.1",
 "vuex-persistedstate": "^3.0.1",
 "web3": "^1.2.1"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
 "@types/node": "^12.7.5",
 "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
 "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
 "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
 "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
 "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
 "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^5.2.0",
 "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
 "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
 "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
 "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
 "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
 "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
 "chai": "^4.1.2",
 "chalk": "^2.0.1",
 "chromedriver": "^2.27.2",
 "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.3",
 "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
 "cross-spawn": "^5.0.1",
 "css-loader": "^3.1.0",
 "eslint": "^4.15.0",
 "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
 "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
 "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
 "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
 "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.0",
 "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
 "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
 "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
 "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
 "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
 "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
 "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
 "inject-loader": "^3.0.0",
 "karma": "^5.1.1",
 "karma-coverage": "^2.0.3",
 "karma-mocha": "^2.0.1",
 "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
 "karma-phantomjs-shim": "^1.4.0",
 "karma-sinon-chai": "^1.3.1",
 "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
 "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.31",
 "karma-webpack": "^2.0.2",
 "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
 "mocha": "^8.0.1",
 "nightwatch": "^1.3.7",
 "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
 "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
 "ora": "^1.2.0",
 "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
 "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
 "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
 "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
 "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
 "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
 "selenium-server": "^3.0.1",
 "semver": "^5.3.0",
 "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
 "sinon": "^4.0.0",
 "sinon-chai": "^2.8.0",
 "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
 "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
 "url-loader": "^2.1.0",
 "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
 "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
 "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
 "webpack": "^4.44.0",
 "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2",
 "webpack-cli": "^3.3.8",
 "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
 "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
 },
 "engines": {
 "node": ">= 6.0.0",
 "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
 },
 "browserslist": [
 "> 1%",
 "last 2 versions",
 "not ie <= 8"
 ]
```

Comment: Is that really the only error output you get? Nothing else?

Comment: Also getting: TypeError: compilation.mainTemplate.applyPluginsWaterfall is not a function

Comment: I have been receiving numerous errors, but have been re-installing several packages, and then obtain different errors, but always related to client@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js`

Comment: I have been googling the different errors, and re-install different packages based on recommended fixes online, and then advance to the next error, but again always related to the webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config error.

Comment: I think this is related: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/841

Comment: Thank you AKX. I have tried npm install html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0 --save-dev, corresponding to last post in link. Now getting following: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'eslint' of undefined